# Почему приложение закрывается при первом срабатывании события?

Tags: ассемблер, циклы, fasm

Пишу простецкое приложение (на FASM), в котором происходит вызов события. Если это событие происходит 10 раз, то приложение должно закрываться, иначе работа продолжится. Я написал код, приложение закрывается при первом же срабатывании события, в чём ошибка:
Код:

```
button_event:

    add [accum],    1d
    cmp [accum], 10d
    je  close_program
    jmp wait_event
close_program:

    mcall   -1
...

DATA

accum   dw  1d
```

Comment: Если Вы пишите на ассемблере и Вам нужна помощь, то:

 1. Пишите название и версию программы для ассемблера
 2. Приводите полный листинг кода, а не огрызки
 3. Пишите на какой и под какую платформу компилируете(DOS, Win32, Win64, Linux, etc)

---------------

Так же можете попробовать обратиться на форум wasm.ru